# Incorrect button mapping when using Xbox 360 wireless controller on LG G3 running Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb-on-the-go, lg-g3, game-controllers

When I plug in the Xbox 360 wireless controller dongle to my LG G3 running Android 5.0 Lollipop and load up a game such as Goat Simulator or Stranger Oddworld, the triggers are mapped to the right analogue stick.  This means my view constantly rotates and moves upward. This is because the inputs are registering `-1.0`. When I move the triggers toward the centre of movement, the view stabilises.

Can the triggers be remapped?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the LG G3 doesn't support the wireless controller. Upon plugging in a wired controller, it worked perfectly